# Web Audio API - Removing filter while playing

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to remove a filter node without having to interrupt the playback?
As far as I understand the node graph has to be rebuilt to "turn something off"?

My Graph looks like this:

```
Source-->GainNode-->LowpassFilter-->HighshelfFilter-->Destination
```

So I want to toggle the HighshelfFilter ON / OFF but it doesn't seem to work without stopping the audio from playing.

I also tried to set `filter.type = 'allpass';` but that causes some weird acoustic effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to do this is to set up parallel connections, one with filtering and one direct, and then crossfade between them (i.e. each has a gain node, and one of the gain nodes set to 0.0 and one set to 1.0).  Routing would look like this:

```
Source-->GainNode1-->LowpassFilter-->HighshelfFilter-->Destination
      ↳->GainNode2-----------------------------------↗︎
```

Start out with one of the gain nodes set to 0.0 and one to 1.0, then switch between them like this:

```
// activate the filters - using setTarget to do a fast crossfade will avoid clicks
gainNode1.gain.setTargetAtTime(1.0, audioCtx.currentTime + 1, 0.001);
// deactivate the direct line
gainNode2.gain.setTargetAtTime(0.0, audioCtx.currentTime + 1, 0.001);
```

You could, as you suggested, make a change to the filter itself that causes it to not have any significant effect.  Instead of an all-pass, maybe try a "peaking"-type filter with a .gain of 0.0?  I don't know precisely how this will affect all the phase relationships, though (that's why the allpass sounds odd).

Finally, a not-recommended approach - you can disconnect and reconnect the nodes.  This WILL cause clicks or pops if there's active audio.  (This is what the sample pointed to above does.)